# Explanation of the usage of Was And IS

Tags: tense

Says i have this sentence:

> The Jolly Roger flying from the mast of the approaching ship indicated
>   that it **was** a pirate ship

We use **was** here because the ship can no longer be a pirate ship in the future

And this :

> The voice of the aprroaching person indicated that he **is** my father

I'm confused about using **is** or **was** in this situation

Any explanation is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both of these sentences the verb in the head clause, *indicated*, fixes the  'Reference Time' (RT, the time you are talking about) in the past. That RT establishes a time context—the linguist Renaat Declerck<sup>†</sup> calls this a temporal ‘domain’—to which closely integrated subordinate clauses are ordinarily related. At the times you are talking about:

- The approaching ship **was** a pirate ship. —*we are not concerned with the ship’s present status, whether it is now a pirate ship or has been captured or sunk, only with its status at the time of your narrative*
- The approaching person **was** your father.  —*we are not concerned with his present status, whether he is still alive or has disowned you, only with his status at the time of your narrative*

This is not an inviolable rule; it may be overridden in a different context. For instance, if you are reviewing your firm’s current financial status, you might allude to a conversation in the recent past but report what was *indicated* in the present tense:

> I spoke with Jack yesterday and he **indicated** that the Offenburger account **is** still delinquent.

Here the context is a present RT, which you drop out of only temporarily to mention your source. But in your examples the RT is clearly past: your concern is with the identity of the ship and the person at that past time.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>With various co-authors in a number of articles and books  from 1989 to 2006. A brief online treatment is [A model of the English tense system](http://www.isc.cnrs.fr/trddeclerck.htm); unfortunately, the illustrations there are unintelligible in the html encoding.</sub>